# Fixed: Knife create instance failing - ERROR: uninitialized constant Chef::Mixin::Command

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef, ruby, knife

I'm wondering if any of you guys have a clue on what is the problem here.
I'm using Chef Knife EC2 plugin to create a new instance.

After completing the ssh connection step, it seems to break on chef-full.erb.

```
Waiting for sshd access to become available

Connecting to xx.xxx.xxx.xx
DEBUG: Looking for bootstrap template in /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/templates
DEBUG: Found bootstrap template in /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/templates
ERROR: uninitialized constant Chef::Mixin::Command
```

the template folder has only a README.md and chef-full.erb and seem to be standard code....

Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

My Chef has been ridden with dependencies failing to load requiring explicitly doing so.

On the plugin file I use, abstracting knife ec2, to spawn new instances I add

```
require 'chef/mixin/command'
```

to the top